# Existence of certain probability distributions on the set of all partitions of a finite set

Tags: co.combinatorics

Conjecture: Let $N$ be a non-empty and finite set. There exists a probability distribution $p$ on the set of all partitions of $N$, $Z(N)$, such that $$\sum_{P\in Z(N):S\in P}p(P)= {1 \over n\cdot \binom{n-1}{s-1}}$$ for all $S\subseteq N:S\ne \emptyset$, where $p(P)$ denotes the probability of partition $P$, $n=|N|$, $s=|S|$.

Trivial? Known? Drops from deeper results? Any idea?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this statement is of interest?

Comment: I don't know whether this is particulary interesting from a purely mathematical perspective. I posted this on a whim mainly as a brain teaser. But there is some serious background. Actually, I had proved this conjecture in a working paper on the potential of the Shapley value due to Hart and Mas-Colell (1989, Potential, value, and consistency, Econometrica 57, 589-614). And I was wondering  whether this already was shown elsewhere or whether there is an interesting proof other than mine.

Answer (score 5):

Recall that the number of permutations $\sigma$ of a set $N$ of cardinality $n$
for which a given non-empty subset $S\subset N$ of cardinality $s$  is an orbit (that is a $\sigma$-invariant subset   generated by some element $x\in N$, whose complement is also $\sigma$-invariant)  is, of course, just $(s-1)!(n-s)! $.

So we may interpret the ratio $$\frac{1} {n {n-1 \choose s-1}}=\frac{(s-1)!(n-s)!}{n!}\qquad\qquad{\bf (1)}$$ as the probability that the subset $S$  be an orbit  of a  permutation of $N$, uniformly chosen at random.

Therefore, a probability distribution on $Z(N)$ that fulfills your requirement is
just the law of the map  $\operatorname{Orb}: {\frak S}(N)\to Z(N)$ (that takes a permutation  into its  orbit partition) seen as a random variable based on ${\frak S}(N)$, with its uniform   probability distribution. In particular 
we have, for  $ P\in Z(N)$
$$p(P)=\frac{1}{n!} \prod_{S\in P}(|S|-1)! \qquad\qquad{\bf (2)}$$

Also note that $p$ is unique, under the obvious  independence and symmetry assumptions that allow to deduce  formula (2)  .